# Построение предложения, пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

**Идея обрести спасение Божье.**

Правильно ли составлено предложение?
Нужны ли какие-либо знаки препинания?

Comment: При таком порядке слов в сочетании обычно пишут "БожИе".

Comment: Без контекста невозможно дать однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если это предложение, а не словосочетание, то надо поставить тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным инфинитивом:

**Идея  ― обрести спасение Божье.**

Но в общем случае нужен контекст. Словосочетание может являться назывным предложением, открывающим тему, тогда знаков препинания нет.